# Nokia ringtones file location

Tags: 9.0-pie, nokia-6

I have a Nokia 6.1 that has some ringtones that aren't in the system/media/audio directory.  Any idea where they'd be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in system/media_cust/audio

Answer (score 0):

On Nokia 5.4
/system/product/media/audio